# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Cookie Authentication loop to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

When I successfully signed in to the HTTP context and I'm redirected to the home controller, the Authorize Attribute of the HomeController redirects me to the login path, because I don't know. (Infinite loop)

The validate async method doesn't sign me out or reject the cookie (I checked it.)

But where's the problem?
I have the same authentication process in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 project and there it works perfectly.

I test it with a custom authorize attribute to check the context. In the context I've a principal and I'm authenticated.

But why redirect me the standard authorize attribute?

My configuration is:

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View("Index");
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/auth/login/";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
                options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = ValidateAsync;
            });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddAntiforgery();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        });
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if(env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }

public static async Task ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        String userId = context.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

        if(userId == null)
        {
            context.RejectPrincipal();
            await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return;
        }

        ApplicationDbContext dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        User user = await dbContext.Users.FindAsync(Guid.Parse(userId));

        if(user == null)
        {
            context.RejectPrincipal();
            await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return;
        }

        if(!user.StaySignedIn && 
            user.LastLogin != null && 
            (user.LastLogin.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)) > DateTimeOffset.Now))
        {
            context.RejectPrincipal();
            await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return;
        }
    }
```

AuthController.cs

```
[Route("/login")]
    [Route("/auth/login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm]LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        Claim nameIdentifier = new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString());

        ClaimsIdentity userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { nameIdentifier }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

        await this.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal);
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

The order of

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Must be changed and then it works.

Comment: You are the man! I had the exact same issue with OneLogin OpenId Connect and NetCore 3.1. The solution worked perfectly. First goes UseAuthentication and then UseAuthorization. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue closed When using identity is not allowed to use the cookies.
It overrides some of the information.
[Git Discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21403)

Answer (score 0):

Cookie options tell the authentication middleware how the cookie works in the browser.In the Startup class, add this code in your ConfigureServices Method

```
     services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options => { options.LoginPath = "/Login"; });
```

Comment: While a code only answer is allowed it is typically encouraged to explain your answer with a little more detail. That way down the line more people are able to benefit from this.